# Cant authenticate to remote vps using ssh in gitlab

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, vps, private-key

I connected before to vps using below gitlab ci/cd configuration. But in recent server I can't.

my .yml file is like below:

```
deploy:
  environment:
    name: production
    url: http://erfantahvieh.com/
  image: php:7.1.1
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -yqq
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

  script:
    - ssh $USER@$HOST "ls -la"
```

Know when I run my pipe line the output is like below:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ echo -e "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 201
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (rsa w/o comment)
$ ssh-keyscan -H $HOST >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
# xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
# xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ ssh $USER@$HOST "ls -la"
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

What is wrong?
Why I connected before by exactly same code but now I can't?
Is there any thing that I missed?

Note: I create ssh private key in my vps and put it in secret var in
gitlab ci/cd settings like $HOST and $USER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happen because you should have `authorized_keys` file in your `.ssh` folder to let other machines to login you server using `ssh private key`.

You can create this file if there isn't by below commands.

```
cd ~/.ss
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
systmctl restart sshd
```